# How do I validate in karate that a json attribute is returned as some string?

Tags: java, cucumber, karate, bdd, gherkin

In Karate tests, I'd like to evaluate whether an attribute returned in json response is of string type.
Below is what am doing:

```
* def abc = response.results.abc
Then match abc == "#string?"
```

Below is the response am getting:

`actual: 'lion', expected: '#string?', reason: did not evaluate to 'true'`

Please let me know where I am wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#schema-validation

```
* def response = { abc: 'foo' }
* match response.abc == '#string'
```

It is recommended you match JSON objects all at once, your tests will be more crisp.

```
* match response == { abc: '#string' }
```